# duplicate symbol ___llvm_profile_runtime in

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch, xcconfig

I am implementing Exact target SDK v5.1.1 as mention on [link](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/get-started/apple.html). But encounter an issue as bellow

```
duplicate symbol ___llvm_profile_runtime in:
    /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.1.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.profile_iossim.a(InstrProfilingRuntime.cc.o)
    /Users/abhijeetb/Documents/Projects/BitBucket/FixIssue/project_folder/project_name/MarketingCloudSDK/MarketingCloudSDK.framework/MarketingCloudSDK(__llvm_profile_runtime.o)
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

In our project, we have -all_load in other linking flag along with -Obj-C, -lc++, -lz, -liconv, If I remove -all_load flag then issue will not occur but not sure about the consequences.

Please guid me to resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Click on your project in Xcode and go to Build phases. 
Look for **__llvm_profile_runtime.o** in `compile sources` and click on it and remove it from `compile sources`

Check to see that you aren't compiling the same file more than once.
If you search for **__llvm_profile_runtime** it should only show up once

Comment: Thanks for you reply but I don't have any file in the compile sources with the name '__llvm_profile_runtime'

Comment: Maybe InstrProfilingRuntime.cc.o, otherwise check for any duplicated files you can see and remove them